# Pyquil run_and_measure gives the same output across all the trials: is this expected?

Tags: programming, pyquil

I tried to run the starter program demonstrated on this page:
http://docs.rigetti.com/en/stable/start.html#installing-the-qvm-and-compiler-on-linux-deb

With the following code:

```
# construct a Bell State program
p = Program(H(0), CNOT(0, 1))

# run the program on a QVM
qc = get_qc('9q-square-qvm')
result = qc.run_and_measure(p, trials=10)
for i in range(10):
    print(result[i])
```

And all of `result[i]`'s turn out to be the same.

Is this expected?
If not, what might I be doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

> And all of result[i]'s turn out to be the same.

This is what I get from the program you posted:

```
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(result[i])
KeyError: 9
```

The first 2 arrays are not the same as the rest, but they are correlated (that's what happens after `CNOT` is applied to an `H`).

The key error is because you are performing a `run_and_measure` on a 9 qubit device and you are trying to print `10` measurement arrays. Studying the [docs](http://docs.rigetti.com/en/stable/apidocs/autogen/pyquil.api.QuantumComputer.run_and_measure.html) for `run_and_measure`: "This will measure all the qubits on this QuantumComputer, not just qubits that are used in the program. Returns a dictionary keyed by qubit index where the corresponding value is a 1D array of measured bits."

Let's print out result

```
print(result)
#0: array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 1: array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 2: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 3: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 4: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 5: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 6: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 7: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 8: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
```

You can see that the `10` different results from `run_and_measure` of the first qubit and second are the same and the rest are `0`'s cause we don't apply gates to them.